# How to Add a Custom Payload to DialogFlow

Tags: angular, dialogflow-es

I've created a basic app with a chatbot that can respond to what I type using DialogFlow and Angular. It is hosted locally. Now I want to have that chatbot respond to what I type with cards, lists and such. Like how Messenger has templates. I want to have a custom payload sent to me in response to what I send. Can anyone please help me?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment Look at the Response section.You need to put you custom payload in the data paramters in your webhook response if using the v1 api.
If you don't use webhook ,you can just add a custom payload response in the intent page.[A pic show this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljr0O.png)